# UIButton and UIBarButtonItems stay in highlighted mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I just took over an enterprise app with over 40k lines of code and I see a strange issue. All the UIButtons and UIBarButtonItems stay in highlighted mode after first tap. So if you touch down on a UIBarButtonItem, it reduces its alpha as expected but it stays the same way on touch up.

I do not see an subclass, category, or extension for UIButton or UIBarButtonItem. I also tried dragging and dropping a new UIButton in IB and the same thing happens. I noted one interesting thing. If on tap, I disable and then re-enable the button, it goes to normal mode but does not go into a highlighted state on further touch downs.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to find the cause?

Comment: Check for any UIButton categories.

Comment: There are no UIButton categories

Comment: That's an annoying issue indeed. I would check KVO code, search workspace with 'UIButton', check `UIAppearance` code, in-storyboard KVC code (in the identity pane), double check subclasses & categories, clean & build, ...etc.